# Moving a ASP.NET application to the cloud

Tags: asp.net, cloud, cloud-hosting

I am new to cloud computing, so please bear with me here. I have an existing ASP.NET application with SQL Server 2008 hosted on a Virtual Private Server. Here's what it briefly does:

1. The front end accepts user's requests and adds them to a DB table
2. A Windows Service running in the background picks up the request, processes it and sets a flag.
3. The Windows Services also creates a file for the user to download.
4. User downloads file

I'd like to move this web application with the service to the cloud. The architecture I envision is that I'll have 1 Web server in which I will install the front end and the windows service. I'll also have a cloud files server for file storage. The windows service should somehow create a file and transfer it to the cloud file server (I assume this is possible?)

My questions:

1. Does the architecture look like I am going in the right direction?
2. I know Amazon has been providing cloud services for a long time. If I want to do minimal changes to my application, should I go with Amazon, Rackspace, Azure or some other provider?
3. I understand that I would not only pay for file storage and web server but also for the bandwidth of users downloading the file and the windows servic uploading the file to the cloud server. Can I assume these costs are negligible? Should I go with VPS + Cloud Files combination to begin with?

Any other thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: What are your objectives? Speeding up downloads for users, or using fewer server resources? 

Also: How many people will be downloading each file - just that one user it's created for?

Comment: With a cloud file server, I will be able to free up server resources in the web server (since files will be stored for a long time and these are large files). Each file will be downloaded by a single user one or more times.

Comment: Your question covers many aspects.  The original question talks about moving the web app and the service to the cloud.  Yet your follow up comment said that you want to free up server resource in the web server, implying you want the web app to remain on the web server (which is in your VPS).  That sounds contradictory.

Comment: @Khnle - I am contemplating on both the approaches and need insight on someone experienced with this. I can either entirely move the application to the cloud (1 cloud web server and 1 cloud file server) or have a combo (1 VPS web server and 1 cloud file server)

Comment: @user102533 - I see and that's what I thought too.  About the economics, it won't be cheap once you touch azure.  Unless I miscalculate (which could very well be), just to have to app sitting in the Azure cloud and do nothing, you're still paying 12 cents/hours.  So that's almost 90/month.

Comment: @Khnle - Any thoughts on the architecture and the other providers listed?

Comment: Be aware you will also be paying for 24x7 CPU time in the cloud. For Amazon EC2, assuming a Win2003 "small" machine you are looking at $86/month. For Azure, double those costs because you need an Application and a Service, and you may need to rewrite parts to work with Azure. Rackspace/EC2 you can just deploy.

Comment: @cdm9002 - Why did MS come up with a cloud technology that involves rewrite? As much as I'd like to stick to MS as much as possible, this can be a hinderance for those looking to move in and out of the cloud

Answer (score 0):

@user102533,

The scenario you describe is very close to the one we cover in this [guide](http://waag.blob.core.windows.net/partone/index.html). You can also download the documents [here](http://wag.codeplex.com/releases/view/45438).

The web site should be fairly staright forwrad to move. The key things to consider:
- Authentication 
- Session management
- Bandwidth use and latency considerations (e.g. big ViewState, etc)

The Windows Service will have to be refactored into a "Worker". This is covered in the guide above with more detail for very similar purposes.

The guide comes with full samples showing how to do it.

Hope it helps
Eugenio

Comment: Went to your first link. My browser attempts to save index.html instead of displaying it. So something must be wrong with your server setup.

Comment: @Eugene - Thanks for the guide. Does moving the application to a different cloud provider other than Azure requires me to go through the same steps outlined in the document?

Comment: @Eugene

It is a Silverlight based app, that might explain it. Are you using Chrome? (same happened to me with Chrome). Anyway, as said, the same content is avialable as world documents.

Comment: @user102533, 

This guide is Windows Azure specific in genral, but some considerations are very general and apply to any cloud (e.g. the identity integration challenges, SSO, bandwidth, etc). Others considerations use Win Azure specific facilities (e.g. Queues). I guess you can extrapolate the same core principles.

Comment: The contnet is now visible in Chrome (not very nicely rendered though..., we'll try to fix it)